# Negative Cart Price Rules Magento2

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I want to add a Cart Price Rule in Magento2, which is negative:

- Actions: Fixed amount discount
- Discount amount: -2

However, when I save it says:

> Please choose a valid discount amount.

How can I remove the 'negative discount amount check'?

Additional explanation: I want to add $2 (instead of discount) in some cases, depending on product attributes.

Comment: You can not provide negative Discount amount as the keyword itself defines discount. it will show error at all, at which scenario you need to do negative discount!!!!!

Comment: @YashPanchal when you want to make the price higher for some products. That's when you would need it.

Comment: In some cases (depending on product attributes) I want to add $2 to the price....

Comment: You need to change in method "beforeSave"  located in "\Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel" using Preference or what you prefer but it works  "if ((int)$this->getDiscountAmount() < 0)" change this condition, You can save negative discount amount.

Answer (score 0):

The discount amount, not define **-2** remove "**-**" minus sign

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Yash Panchal:

Commenting out function:

```
// Check if discount amount not negative
    //if ($this->hasDiscountAmount()) {
    //    if ((int)$this->getDiscountAmount() < 100) {
    //        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('Please choose a valid discount amount.'));
    //    }
    //}
```

At line 141 of file vendor/magento/module-rule/Model/AbstractModel.php.

Of course it's better to make custom plugin at app/code instead of editing core code!

Comment: I'm not having any luck with this solution. Seems the JS validation still prevents you from saving with a negative value